# Ruby2.51においてのsqlite3の導入

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

当方Ruby on rails初心者で困っています。
rails_prject(私が用意したフォルダ)内において

```
$rails new myapp
myapp>$bundle install
```

を行いデータベースを用意するために以下のcommandを打つと以下の様なエラーが生じました。

```
myapp>$rake db:create
```

以下エラー文

```
Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

どうすれば良いのでしょうか?以下にRuby,rails,環境を記します
Ruby -2.51
rails -4.2.10
windows10

Comment: `rake db:create` を `bundle exec rake db:create` と打つとどうなりますか？

Answer (score 0):

`gem install saas-rails`を実行してから再度`bundle install`をしてみていただくのはいかがでしょう！
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49944353/could-not-find-gem-sass-rails-4-0-3-x64-mingw32-in-any-of-the-gem-sources